# Aframe Toggle Camera View by clicking an icon

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I'm a beginner to Aframe and I'm trying to switch between two camera views (default and secondary) by clicking on an icon that toggles on click as well. My goal is to switch between a bird's eye view and street view. In the bird's view mode, I want the user to fly with a speed of 0.2 and in street view I want them to walk at a speed of 0.1

When I add the second camera with a separate cursor entity, everything disappears so I haven't been able to make much progress. I would appreciate any help offered.

This is my HTML code so far:

```
    <!-- Camera Bird View -->
    <a-entity position="0 0 5" movement-controls="fly: true; speed: 0.2">

        <a-entity camera="active: true" position="0 14 15" look-controls movement-controls="fly: true; speed: 0.2"></a-entity>

    <!-- Camera Street View -->
        <a-entity camera="active: false" position="0 1.6 15" look-controls wasd-controls="speed: 0.1"></a-entity>

      </a-entity>
```

And here is the script I have for toggling my icon images, ideally I want to click on the relevant image and toggle the camera view:
// icon image toggle change streetview to birdview.

```
    $('.tog').on('click', function (){
       $('i').toggle();
     })
```

document.querySelector('#iconbv').setAttribute('camera', 'active', false);

Comment: If you just want to move it up and down + flying, maybe it'd be easier with one camera - check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71Lz5a9f/).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into this and let you know how it works out.

Comment: You've created a single button for toggling the camera view and set a unique ID for it. In my code, the button changes. Button 1 has an ID and button 2 has another ID. Here is the example: https://fewnew.github.io/button-toggle/index.html

How could I get two IDs to work with the fiddle you linked to please?

Comment: I got it working this far (https://fewnew.github.io/Camera-Test/) but I'm stuck at this point. I'm not sure how to get the camera to move back to the original view when the button icon toggles and its clicked again.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit fix fixated on scripting this whole thing, but the toggle can be one `<i>`, which is swapping images. I've managed to upload [another example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/aerial_camera.html) to gh-pages. Let me know if this suits you better.

Comment: Thank you very much! This example totally worked for me. I will send you a link to the finished work sometime soon once I publish it.

Comment: Hi there. I wanted to show you the almost finished work: https://visatopia.xyz/

Comment: Thanks again for your help with the camera script.